# Upload junittest report to Jira-Zephyr from GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, jira-zephyr

I created a JUnit test report on GitHub Actions and now I need to send this to Zephyr.
On Zephyr, it is possible to import the report manually but I haven't found an API or anything else.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: can you please comment any links you have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey in case you still need that info, you can use this documentation to import to Zephyr scale. In case you have Zephyr Squad I suppose it will be different, or even not possible (not sure though).
https://support.smartbear.com/zephyr-scale-cloud/api-docs/#tag/Automations/operation/createJUnitExecutions

To run that endpoint you will also need a token, which you can get by following these steps:
https://support.smartbear.com/zephyr-scale-cloud/docs/rest-api/generating-api-access-tokens.html

I found this video useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZcFYFbci8U&ab_channel=TimotiusPamungkas

Hope this helps